# Why loading 4000 images into redis using spark-submit takes time (9 Minutes) longer than loading the same images into HBase (2.5 Minutes)?

Tags: redis, hbase, spark-submit

Loading Images into Redis should be much faster than doing the same thing using Hbase since Redis deals with RAM while HBase uses HDFS to store the data. I was surprised when I loaded 4000 images into Redis, it took 9 Minutes to finish! While the same process I've done using HBase and It took only 2.5 Minutes. Is there an interpretation for this? Any Suggestions to improve my code? Here is my code:

```
// The code for loading the images into Hbase (adopted from NIST)
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Fingerprint.LoadData") 
val sc = new SparkContext(conf) 
Image.dropHBaseTable() Image.createHBaseTable() 
val checksum_path = args(0) 
println("Reading paths from: %s".format(checksum_path.toString)) 
val imagepaths = loadImageList(checksum_path) println("Got %s images".format(imagepaths.length))
imagepaths.foreach(println) 
println("Reading files into RDD") 
val images = sc.parallelize(imagepaths).map(paths => Image.fromFiles(paths._1, paths._2)) 
println(s"Saving ${images.count} images to HBase")
Image.toHBase(images) 
println("Done")

} val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Fingerprint.LoadData") val sc = new SparkContext(conf) Image.dropHBaseTable() Image.createHBaseTable() val checksum_path = args(0) println("Reading paths from: %s".format(checksum_path.toString)) val imagepaths = loadImageList(checksum_path) println("Got %s images".format(imagepaths.length)) imagepaths.foreach(println) println("Reading files into RDD") val images = sc.parallelize(imagepaths) .map(paths => Image.fromFiles(paths._1, paths._2)) println(s"Saving ${images.count} images to HBase") Image.toHBase(images) println("Done")

} def toHBase(rdd: RDD[T]): Unit = {

     val cfg = HBaseConfiguration.create()
     cfg.set(TableOutputFormat.OUTPUT_TABLE, tableName)
     val job = Job.getInstance(cfg)
     job.setOutputFormatClass(classOf[TableOutputFormat[String]])
     rdd.map(Put).saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset(job.getConfiguration)

}
```

//The code for Loading images intto Redis

```
  val images = sc.parallelize(imagepaths).map(paths => Image.fromFiles(paths._1, paths._2)).collect
        for(i <- images){
val stringRdd = sc.parallelize(Seq((i.uuid, new String(i.Png, StandardCharsets.UTF_8))))
        sc.toRedisKV(stringRdd)(redisConfig)
        stringRdd.collect}                    
        println("Done")
```

Comment: Mmmm - it will depend on your environment which you haven't specified and the size of the images and the type of your disks. A Raspberry Pi Zero with an SD card and 512MB of RM may perform differently from a 16-core workstation with SSD drives and 128GB of RAM... also Redis is single threaded...

Comment: What client library are you using to connect to redis? How many threads and physical machines do you upload them from?

Comment: Thanks for your reply Imas I have a cluster of three VMs for both Redis and Hbase. I'm using the same hardware configurations for both. Here is the code related to Redis configurations:

val conf=new SparkConf()
    .setMaster("yarn-cluster")
    .setAppName("LoadDataIntoRedis")     
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)    
    val redisServerDnsAddress = "*.*.*.*"
    val redisPortNumber = 6379
    val redisPassword = "***********"
    val redisConfig = new RedisConfig(new RedisEndpoint(redisServerDnsAddress,  redisPortNumber, redisPassword))

Comment: i'm just using this library: import com.redislabs.provider.redis._

Comment: @MarkSetchell how did you know that Redis is single threaded? I have one Master node, 2 Slaves.

each node has 6G RAM, 2 Cores, 4G swap.

Size of dataset is around 900 MB.

When I checked the swap size for each node, I discovered that swap size is decreased for all nodes even though RAM size for two slaves is still more than 2GB. This also surprised me, why swap is used even though slaves nodes has sufficient RAM capacity which is enough to fit the loaded dataset?Thank you.